# Rails delete functionality is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-4

I am completely new to Ruby On Rails, and going through [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-rails) to build a basic application.

When I am trying to implement the delete functionality as mentioned in the document, I am seeing the show page.

I have below method in my controller:

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy

  redirect_to articles_path
end
```

and below line in my page:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Now when I click on the link, I am seeing below URL in browser:

> http://localhost:3000/articles/1

Now now in this case I am seeing the show screen instead of getting an alert message and then deleting the record from my page.

I have followed this SO post - [Rails 4 link_to Destroy not working in Getting Started tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154916/rails-4-link-to-destroy-not-working-in-getting-started-tutorial)

and verified that

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

elements are there in my `application.js`

Please tell me where I am doing mistake?

**Update:**

Here is my output of `rake routes` command:

```
E:\Rails\blog\bin>rake routes
(in E:/Rails/blog)
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
              POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
  new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
 edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
      article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
              PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
         root GET    /                            welcome#index
```

This is what I get from log files when I click on Delete link:

```
Started GET "/articles/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-09 00:56:08 +0530
Processing by ArticlesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  [1m[35mArticle Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 46.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

In my `application.html.erb` file, I have modified the text `application` to `default` to fix an issue that I reported in this post - [ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116966/execjsprogramerror-in-welcomeindex-typeerror-object-doesnt-support-this-pro) , is this the cause of my issue now? If revert the change, then the application is failing completely.

Comment: Have a look in `log/development.log` to see what route is being trigger and what errors, if any, are generated. When working on a Rails app you should probably have a `tail -f log/development.log` or equivalent open all the time to catch mistakes like this early.

Comment: @tadman He probably started the Rails app with `rails server`. That will boot the app and show the development log, but yes... you shouldn't see `Started GET "/articles/1" ...` in your log, since you are using `method: :delete`.

Comment: show us your entry in config/routes.rb  for this route please

Comment: It's sounding a lot like the `application.js` file is not included in the layout.

Comment: @ilanberci, updated my question with the list of routes

Comment: @tadman, added output from log file, also I have updated with what changes I made to application.html.erb, please check.

Comment: @newmediafreak, please check the log output

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `button_to` instead of `link_to` to make it work.

Refer to this post - [Rails 3 - link_to :delete is redirecting to show action with jquery installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934196/rails-3-link-to-delete-is-redirecting-to-show-action-with-jquery-installed) , look at the answer given by Cypher.

Comment: I was having this same error and changing from "link_to" to "button_to" made my application work. Could you or somebody else please elaborate on why link_to does not work and whether there is a way to make it work as desired?

Comment: @EthanMelamed link_to creates the <a> tag for links. This tag is always a GET. JavaScript is then used to modify the link to become a DELETE request. This JavaScript helper is in rails.js. If either rails.js is not properly loaded, or JavaScript is not enabled in your browser, then it will stay a GET request. One workaround for to avoid the JavaScript is to use button_to, which provides a form, not a link.

Answer (score 0):

This post is already solved but for those who ran into the same problem using rails guides 7.0.3 where turbo was used this method can be used to solve it

> gem install turbo,
> rails importmap:install,
> rails turbo:install,
> rails turbo:install:redis,

in the exact order. note: there is no need to change link_to to button_to